# SASS Mixin e Hover: como escrever o hover trocando parâmetros do mixin?

Tags: css, sass

Oi. Eu sou novo no SASS, então peço desculpas se for uma dúvida boba, mas não encontrei lugar nenhum na internet com resposta pra ela, então...

Eu estou trabalhando num projeto que tem um modelo de botão. Criei um mixin pra definir como ele será.

```
@mixin btn($bg:#fff, $color:$blue, $border:none) {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 35px 16px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: $border;
    border-radius: 50% 0;
    background: $bg;
    color: $color;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Quando eu chamo o botão, posso passar propriedades diferentes pelos parâmetros para criar variações de cor e etc.

```
.main-btn {
    @include btn($bg:transparent,$border:2px solid $blue);
}
```

Minha pergunta é a seguinte: se eu quiser fazer um hover nesse botão, tem algum modo de eu escrever ele mudando apenas os valores dos parâmetros do mixin, pra não ficar escrevendo todas as mudanças do hover por extenso (tipo "background-color: $blue", "color: #fff", etc)?

Eu pensei em fazer algo assim:

```
.main-btn {
    @include btn($bg:transparent, $border:2px solid $blue);
    &:hover {
        @include btn($bg:$blue, $color:#fff, $border:none);
    }
}
```

Mas, quando eu faço, ele realmente faz o include inteiro do mixin, reescrevendo inclusive todas as propriedades padrões estáticas de novo, e aí o arquivo .css fica enorme.

**Há alguma forma de fazer o hover apenas trocando os valores dos parâmetros passados num mixin já incluso na classe?**

Comment: Acho que para o que vc quer fazer o correto é o Placeholder e não o Mixin veja aqui https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors

Comment: Boa idéia! Usei o placeholder só pros atributos de valor fixo, e usei o mixin da mesma forma que escrevi no final do meu post, só que apenas pros valores variáveis (background-color, color e border-color). Nunca havia entendido bem a diferença entre o placeholder e o mixin, mas esse artigo aqui me ajudou muito também (https://tableless.com.br/sass-mixin-ou-placeholder/).